# Numbering table footnotes XSLT 3.0 with xsl:number xsl-fo

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, footnotes

Given this XML:

```
<reqSpares>
    <spareDescrGroup>
        <spareDescr>
            <name>Bulb</name>
            <footnoteRemarks>
              <footnoteRef internalRefId="ftn-0001"/>
              <footnoteRef internalRefId="ftn-0002"/>
            </footnoteRemarks>
        </spareDescr>                           
        <spareDescr>
              <embeddedSpareDescr>
                    <name>small bulb</name>
                    <footnoteRemarks>
                          <footnoteRef internalRefId="ftn-0002"/>
                    </footnoteRemarks>
              </embeddedSpareDescr>
        </spareDescr>
        <footnote id="ftn-0001">
            <para>Make sure the bulb works.</para>
        </footnote>
        <footnote id="ftn-0002">
             <para>Make sure that the new bulb is not cracked.</para>
        </footnote>
    <spareDescrGroup>
</reqSpares>
```

This will be a table with the footnote number in a row and the footnote number and footnote in the table footer.

Desired output (except the footnotes are in a table footer):

| Name | Remarks |
| --- | --- |
| Bulb | 1 2 |
| small bulb | 2 |
| 1 Make sure the bulb works. |  |
| 2 Make sure that the new bulb is not cracked. |  |

Actual output:

| Name | Remarks |
| --- | --- |
| Bulb |  |
| small bulb |  |
| 1 Make sure the bulb works. |  |
| 2 Make sure that the new bulb is not cracked. |  |

The footnotes are displaying correctly in the footer, but `xsl:number` is not working in `<footnoteRef>` (it's blank)

This also works in `<footnote>` but not `<footnoteRef>`:

```
<xsl:number count="footnote" from="reqSpares"/>
```

I did not think I needed to be in `<footnote>` to count `<footnote>` with `xsl:number`

XSLT:

```
<xsl:param name="footnote-count-pattern" static="yes" as="xs:string" select="'reqSpares/descendant::footnote'"/>

<xsl:template match="footnoteRemarks">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="footnote">
    <fo:block font-size="75%">
        <xsl:number _count="{$footnote-count-pattern}" level="any"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="footnoteRef">
    <!-- only need footnote number here -->
    <fo:inline baseline-shift="super" font-size="75%">
      <xsl:number _count="{$footnote-count-pattern}" level="any"/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reqSpares">
      <fo:table>          
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-header>
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:block>Name</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:block>Remarks</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-footer>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
              <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::footnote"/>
              </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-footer>
        <fo:table-body>           
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="spareDescr">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
          </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="footnoteRemarks"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `count=reqSpares/descendant::footnote` is counting `footnote` elements, but the context item is a `footnoteref`, so there aren't any `footnote` elements to be counted. You need to navigate to the footnote element. Note that in XSLT 3.0 you can do this using `xsl:number/@select` - you no longer need to reset the context item using `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `<xsl:number select="ancestor::reqSpares[1]/descendant::footnote" count="footnote"/>` and I get the error "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:number" and `<xsl:number select="ancestor::reqSpares[1]/descendant::footnote[1]" count="footnote"/>` displays all ones in the Remarks column.

Comment: Well, you don't want the number of any old footnote, you want the number of the footnote that this footnoteref relates to, so you'll have to select that footnote in your select expression. For example `select="//footnote[@id=current()/@internalRefId]"`

Comment: This worked, of course, thank you, Dr. Kay. I already had a key defined `<xsl:key name="id" match="*[@id]" use="@id"/>` so from your answer I tweaked it to: `<xsl:number select="key('id',@internalRefId)/self::footnote"/>` just to see if that could work.